# How to create column and set name in JavaFx TreeTableView

Tags: javafx, treetableview

how can i create column and set their name from a list of String in JavaFx. Is there a methode like `public String getColumnName(int column)`  and `getColumnCount`as in swingx in JavaFx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the data model for a JavaFX `TreeTableView` is managed differently to the way the data model is managed in Swing.

The data model is represented by two properties in the `TreeTableView` class: `root` and `columns`.

`root` is a `TreeItem<T>` (where `T` is the data type represented by each row of the `TreeTableView`). It has a `getChildren()` method for child elements in the tree structure, expanded state, etc.

`getColumns()` returns an `ObservableList<TreeTableColumn<T,?>>`, which is essentially a list of columns. So the number of columns is determined by the size of this list. `TreeTableColumn` has a `text` property which encapsulates the title of the column. So the column names are represented by the `text` properties of the elements of the list returned by `getColumns()`.

So, to sort of answer your question, given

```
TreeTableView<T> treeTable ;
```

(where `T` is replaced by some actual type), and

```
List<String> columnNames ;
```

you can populate the columns of the tree table with

```
for (String name : columnNames) {
    TreeTableColumn<T,?> column = new TreeTableColumn<>(name);
    treeTable.getColumns().add(column);
}
```

or if you prefer a Java 8 style:

```
columnNames.stream().map(TreeTableColumn::new)
    .forEach(treeTable.getColumns()::add);
```

However, note that you almost certainly need to set a cell value factory on each column, and possibly configure it further in other ways.